# Connecting mysql to visual studio

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a MYSQL database and I wish to connect it to my visual basic application running in visual studio. I know the code once it is connected however I am not sure on how to initially connect it up to visual studio.
I have done it once before using MYSQL-Connector however I cant seem to be able to run the connector.

I am also using a uni-server controller to run the database too

Comment: You need to use mysqlconnection to connect to a mysql database. There are plenty of tutorials out there or slternatively, show us what you gave tried and where you got stuck!

Comment: You should probably add Connector/Net to your project as a NuGet package. You can then access all the types it contains just like you would a standard Microsoft provider.

Comment: Thank you, I tried downloading mysqlconnector from oracle and weirdly it acts as if it hasn't even been downloaded since it wont show up when i search for it

Comment: Are you downloading the nuget package through Visual Studio's Tools menu ->Nuget Package Manager->Manage Nuget Packages for Solution ?

Comment: Also check: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1secsqSWLs

Answer (score 1):

First of all, download the MySQL to vb.net or Visual Studio connector and install.

Go to the solution explorer and right click on the reference > add reference > com (search for myql.dll file) > ok

You are good to go but you can also decide to create a module like this to make connecting to the database easier:

```
  Public Sub dbconnect()

    Try
        Dim connString As String = "server=localhost; uid=root; pwd=; database=databasename"
        conn = New MySqlConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MsgBox("Please make sure your database properly configured", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Database Connection Error")
    End Try

End Sub
```

With this, whenever you want to connect to the database, just call the `Sub dbconnect`.